# How to return two strings in one return statement?

Tags: java

```
public String[] decode(String message)
{
     String ans1 = "hey"; 
     String ans2 = "hi";  
     return {ans1 , ans2};  // Is it correct?
}
```

This above example does not work properly. I am getting a error.

How can I achieve the initial question?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The correct syntax would be

```
 return new String[]{ ans1, ans2 };
```

Even though you've created two `String`s (`ans1` and `ans2`) you haven't created the `String` array (or `String[]`) you're trying to return.  The syntax shown above is shorthand for the slightly more verbose yet equivalent code:

```
String[] arr = new String[2];
arr[0] = ans1;
arr[1] = ans2;
return arr;
```

where we create a length 2 String array, assign the first value to `ans1` and the second to `ans2` and then return that array.

Comment: Why is it so? Ive alderly created a string .. if I create a new string like ans1 = new String[] then will it work?

Comment: @D.J. because even though you have created String objects you haven't yet created a String array (see my edited answer for more details)

Answer (score 10):

```
return new String[] { ans1, ans2 };
```

The reason you have to do do this is just saying { ans1, ans2} doesn't actually create the object you are trying to return.  All it does is add two elements to an array, but without "new String[]" you haven't actually created an array to add the elements to.

Comment: Why is it so? Ive alderly created a string .. if I create a new string like ans1 = new String[] then will it work?

Comment: @D.J Updated my answer with further explanation.

Answer (score 4):

```
return new String[] {ans1 , ans2};
```

Comment: Why is it so? Ive alderly created a string .. if I create a new string like ans1 = new String[] then will it work?

Answer (score 2):

```
return new String[]{ans1,ans2};
```

This should work. To your other question in the comments. Since Java is strongly typed language, all the variables/results should be instantiated. Since you are not instantiating the result you want to return anywhere, we are doing the instantiation in the return statement itself.

Answer (score -1):

I'm only a high school student at the moment, but an easy solution that I got from a friend of mine should work. It goes like this (this is part of a project in my AP class):

```
public String firstMiddleLast()
{
   //returns first, middle, and last names
    return (first + " " + middle + " " + last);
}
```

Comment: And then? The caller has to saperate them again...?